# Where does server socket bind to?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, serversocket

In which IP this `new ServerSocket(port);` bind?
To **all public** IPs and localhost? Not sure about this.
If I have multiple interfaces does it bind to all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This call is the equivalent of

```
new ServerSocket(port, 0, null);
```

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket%28int,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress%29) for this method:

> If bindAddr is null, it will default accepting connections on any/all local addresses.

So yes, it will be bound to all interfaces.

Comment: `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket(int, int, java.net.InetAddress)`

Comment: added link for java7 api doc